# Is there a way to stack the data in excel using VBA

Tags: excel, vba

I have an excel file with 120 columns. Part of the data are as follows:

[image: Exce]

Two important columns are Column M ( Group) and N (Class). I want to get M 1 and M2 from Column Group. Next, I filter Class to get M1 and M2. Next, I will copy copy-paste  M1 and M2, which is obtained from Class, at the end of the data that I obtained from Group and then rename them to M1 and M2. So the output would be:

[image] 
Therefore, Group has only M1 and M2. Thanks for your help

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See [Copy](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.range.copy) method of Range object

```vb
Option Explicit
Sub stack()

    Const START_ROW = 2 ' row below header

    Dim wb As Workbook, ws As Worksheet, count As Integer
    Dim iRow As Long, iLastRow As Long, iTargetRow As Long, s As String

    Set wb = ThisWorkbook
    Set ws = wb.Sheets("Sheet1")

    ' find last row existing data
    iLastRow = ws.Range("M" & Rows.count).End(xlUp).Row
    iTargetRow = iLastRow + 1

    ' scan col M
    For iRow = START_ROW To iLastRow
       s = ws.Cells(iRow, 13).Value ' M
       If s = "M1" Or s = "M2" Then
           ws.Rows(iRow).EntireRow.Copy ws.Cells(iTargetRow, 1)
           iTargetRow = iTargetRow + 1
           count = count + 1
       End If
    Next

    ' scan col N
    For iRow = START_ROW To iLastRow
       s = ws.Cells(iRow, 14).Value ' N
       If s = "M1" Or s = "M2" Then
           ws.Rows(iRow).EntireRow.Copy ws.Cells(iTargetRow, 1)
           ws.Cells(iTargetRow, 13) = s ' copy from N to M
           iTargetRow = iTargetRow + 1
           count = count + 1
       End If
    Next

    MsgBox count & " rows copied.", vbInformation
End Sub
```

Comment: Many thanks, @CDP, I will check and get back to you

Comment: The codes are correct How I can undo my editing? Can you help?

Comment: I think it does work well. If I have the following codes= M1= M600, M2= M200, N1= M60Z and N2= N20Z, How i can change the codes?

Comment: @user Just change "M1" to "M600" and "M2" to "M200". I can't see how the N values are relevant.

Comment: Thanks, they just have a character at the end.